Number of swaps needed in a random 8-ball pool rack to create a valid rack
I'm an engineer, not a mathematician, please don't judge me! I play a lot of pool and I like efficiency so I started wondering what the maximum number of ball swaps were needed to transform a random pool rack into a valid rack. Thinking it through, the answer is 4 - and I'll explain why, then ask my question.
Valid Rack
Random Rack
The aim is to end up at a valid rack. There are 7 yellows and 7 reds. Referring to the image, I'll call yellow the "Dominant colour" in that example rack, and the spaces yellow occupies the "dominant spaces". As long as the dominant spaces are all occupied by a single colour, the rack is valid. The maximum possible non-dominant colours in dominant spaces is 3 otherwise the dominant colour would flip, so the maximum moves to create a valid rack is 3 plus 1 for the black = 4.
Now the fun bit, I wrote some code to brute-force this over 1000s of cycles to see the distribution of the number of moves from random racks to valid racks. The code looks at all the dominant spaces, finds what colour is most represented in them (the dominant colour), then swaps balls in from the non-dominant spaces as needed to create a valid rack. I expected an approximately Normal Distribution, with 0 moves (a perfect rack) being very low, 2 and 3 moves being common, and 4 being less common - but that is not what I see. 4 moves is overwhelmingly most common, representing 2/3 of the test outcomes.
Dominant colour by checking all dominant spaces
Next, I modified the code slightly to represent how I personally set up a pool rack - I look at the diagonal triplet of colours to the left and base my dominant colour only on which colour is most dominant in that. This should give us a maximum of 6 moves (assume worst case that there are 2 dominant colours in this triplet, but the other 5 of that colour are in the wrong places, so moves is 5 plus the black = 6).
When I run the brute-force code using that method for finding the dominant colour, I DO see a normal distribution from 0 to 6 moves. 4 moves still represents the most common at ~1/2 of test cycles, but it is a normal curve.
Dominant colour by checking only triplet colours
So, why do I NOT see a normal distribution when I pick the dominant colour by looking at all the dominant spaces, and why DO I see a normal distribution when I pick the dominant colour by just looking at the triplet?

The point is that you shouldn't expect to see anything resembling a normal distribution in the first case. If you were counting the number of swaps to move yellow to the dominant position, you would get something that looks a lot more normal (with a range from 0 to 8).
Let's assume for simplicity that black didn't start in the right position, but you have swapped it already. Most of the time there would now be 3 or 4 yellows in the dominant position, which correspond to a middling number of swaps (5 or 4, assuming black had to be swapped). Less often you would have 2 or 5 yellows in dominant positions (6 or 3 swaps), less often still 1 or 6 yellows (7 or 2 swaps), and the most extreme cases are very unlikely.
But by choosing the most efficient colour, the most common case of having a 4-3 split in the dominant spaces (after moving the black, if necessary) has become your worst case, and the two extreme cases of having lots of yellows or lots of reds have both become the best case.
So what you should expect is something that looks a bit like the bottom half of a normal distribution: the top half corresponds to cases where you would use the other colour.
In the second protocol, you don't always choose the right colour and so the top half is partially still there.

Incidentally, is the mirror image of a valid rack still valid? If so, you can improve the number of swaps for some combinations, although there are some starting positions that require four swaps even in this case.

Thanks for the excellent explanation - really clear. Now you have pointed it out it's obvious: the first scenario is the bottom half of a normal curve - flipping the dominant colour at the "best case" point necessarily removes the samples above that point.
Incidentally, my brother is a competitive pool player and pointed out my "rack protocol" is 30 years out of date. In the current British Pool Rules, the rack is subtly different and it is  red dominant - so per the actual current racking rules, the distribution would be normal if I simulated it.

One can collect the statistics over all $51480=15\binom{14}{7}$ possible
read-yellow-black combinations of the racks. The 15 is the number of positions for the black ball and the 14-choose-7 the number of ways of distributing the 2 colors. In C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
#define POSIT 15
class rack
{
public:
        char * col ; // 0=red 1= yellow 3= black
        long trNeed[8] ;
        rack()
        {
                col = new char[POSIT] ;
                for(int t=0  ; t < 8 ; t++)
                        trNeed[t]=0 ;
        } ;

        /* assuming all col[0..POSIT-1] are settled. compute number of transpositions
        * for the maths we may assume that a valid rack has 7 reds [0..6] followed by 7 yellows [7..13] and 1 black [14]
        */
        static int transp(char *full)
        {
                int tr=0 ;
                for(int p=0 ; p < 7 ; p++)
                        if (full[p] != 0 )
                                tr ++ ;
                for(int p=7 ; p < POSIT-1 ; p++)
                        if (full[p] != 1 )
                                tr ++ ;
                if ( full[POSIT-1] != 2)
                        tr ++ ;
                return tr/2 ;
        }

        /* cont statistics of colors remaining considering col[0..piv-1]
        */
        void statRyb(int ryb[3], int piv)
        {
                ryb[0] = ryb[1] = 7 ;
                ryb[2] = 1 ;
                for(int p=0 ; p < piv ; p++)
                        ryb[col[p]]-- ;
        }

        /* piv is the number in the rang 0..14 which
        * has not yet an assigned color
        */
        void swaps(int piv)
        {
                /* put a pall at piv and check recursivey number
                * of swaps needed
                */
                int rem[3] ;
                statRyb(rem,piv) ;
                if (rem[0] > 0)
                {
                        col[piv]=0 ;
                        swaps(piv+1) ;

                }
                if (rem[1] > 0)
                {
                        col[piv]=1 ;
                        swaps(piv+1) ;
                }
                if (rem[2] > 0)
                {
                        col[piv]=2 ;
                        swaps(piv+1) ;
                }
                /* number of positions: 15*binomial(14,7) = 51480
                */
                if ( rem[0] ==0 && rem[1] ==0 && rem[2] == 0)
                {
                        trNeed[transp(col)] ++ ;
                }
                return ;
        }

        void swaps()
        {
                swaps(0) ;
        }
} ;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        rack pool ;
        pool.swaps()  ;
        for(int t=0 ; t < 8 ; t++)
                cout << t << " " << pool.trNeed[t] << endl ;
}

This gives the result of 2 columns: swaps/transpositions needed and number of racks:
0 1
1 161
2 2793
3 12985
4 20825
5 12201
6 2401
7 113

The most likely occurrence with 20825 out of 51480 are 4 swaps needed to adjust. This analysis assumes that rotating the frame by multiples of 120 degrees after setup is not allowed, and that frames where all yellow balls are at red positions need 7 swaps, for example.
